# x := [...]string{"Sat", "Sun"} vs x:= []string{"Sat", "Sun"}

Tags: go, variadic-templates

In the go lang [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec) they used three dots in one of the examples:

```
days := [...]string{"Sat", "Sun"}  // len(days) == 2
```

Does it make any difference if the three dots are left out?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It makes a *pretty big difference*: The difference is between an `array` and a `slice`.

`[]string` creates a slice that points to an array of strings. On the other hand, `[...]` creates an *actual* array of strings.

There is a great [blog post](http://blog.golang.org/slices) about the difference between the two on the golang blog. I'll try to summarize here as best I can.

Arrays in golang are like value types, they are references to a specific type and are always of a specific length. There are two ways to create an array: 1) with explicit length and 2) implicit length:

```
// Explicit length. 
var days := [7]string { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" }

// Implicit length. (Let the compiler figure it out how long it is)
var days := [...]string { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" }
```

These are both equivalent array definitions. Note that the length of an array is *part* of it's type definition. So, you *can't* interchange arrays of similar type with different lengths:

```
// These two are not interchangeable!
var someArray [5]string;
var otherArray [10]string;

func work(data [5]string) { /* ... */ }

work(someArray)  // good
work(otherArray) // not so good
```

Also note that arrays, like structs, are passed as value – a copy of the array will be given to a function, not a reference to it..

Slices, on the other hand, are like reference types. They are backed by an array, but they are more malleable. They include a pointer to a position within array, a length, and a capacity.

```
// Create a slice
var days := []string { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" }
```

Slices, unlike arrays, are not explicitly bound to their length and slices of different lengths can be passed for one another. They also act more like a pointer, which means they get passed by reference, instead of value.

There is also a great post about [Go Data Structures](http://research.swtch.com/godata), and how they are they are represented in memory. I highly recommend checking it out.

Comment: I think that you should swap `someArray` and `otherArray` lengths in your second example :)